# Similar Route on Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade

I have problem on routing in laravel 5.1

here's my route code

```
Route::get('/class-list/{date?}', array('as'=>'class.list', 'uses'=>'ClassController@classlist'));
Route::get('/class-list/{studio_url}/{date?}', array('as'=>'studio.class.list', 'uses'=>'ClassController@classlist'));'
```

and here's my Controller

```
public function classlist($date)
{
    echo $date;
}
```

Can I access `localhost/class-list/2015-08-08` and `localhost/class-list/beefit/2015-08-08` on the same controller? Is it possible? (date is mandatory)

Because now when I access `localhost/class-list/beefit/2015-08-08` it will show `beefit`.. I want it show `2015-08-08` same as when I access `localhost/class-list/2015-08-08`

Comment: If you want to use the same method the parameters have too match from the route and method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using two functions for one route, you should split it up like so

```
Route::get('/class-list/{date?}', array('as'=>'class.list', 'uses'=>'ClassController@classlist'));
Route::get('/class-list/{studio_url}/{date?}', array('as'=>'studio.class.list', 'uses'=>'ClassController@classlist2'));
```

Controller

```
public function classlist($date)
{
    echo $date;
}

public function classlist2($studio_url, $date)
{
    echo $date;
}
```

Note that I changed the **ClassController@classlist** to **ClassController@classlist2**
The word after the @ is the function name inside the controller.

Hope this helps

Comment: is it possible if I'm still using only one controller?

Comment: @xuweisen Yes sure! You can use many functions inside one controller.

Comment: oops, wrong typing.. I mean still using only one function x_x.. sorry

Comment: @xuweisen If you just want to keep one function then u will always need to send the studio_url and date, but its posible just send 0 for studio url and make a check in the code ````if the studio_url is not 0 display this else that````.

Comment: I see.. I understand now.. Okay then I will try it.. thank you very much ^^

Comment: @xuweisen glad I could help